# Why can't I vertically align these two matrices?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, matrices, delimiters

Why won't these matrices become left-aligned?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}&u_{2}&\frac{a_{1}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{2}&u_{1}&\frac{a_{2}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{3}&0&u_{4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\intertext{with} 
&\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}&u_{2}&\frac{a_{1}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{2}&u_{1}&\frac{a_{2}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{3}&0&u_{4}
\end{vmatrix}=1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: They are left-aligned, but the delimiter glyph `[` in this font has a margin.

Comment: Adding a `\!` before the bmatrix almost annihilates this margin (~ 0.5pt of difference in alignment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ***very dirty trick***, but it works. It aligns the matrices' elements rather than the delimiters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}&u_{2}&\frac{a_{1}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{2}&u_{1}&\frac{a_{2}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{3}&0&u_{4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\mathrel{\phantom{=1}}
\intertext{with} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}&u_{2}&\frac{a_{1}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{2}&u_{1}&\frac{a_{2}}{d}u_{3}\\
a_{3}&0&u_{4}
\end{vmatrix}=1
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dirty or not, but it surely does the job. Thank you!

Comment: @user124471 I just realized that the `\mathclap` construct is a non-sense and can be removed. It is much less dirty now :)